# Android-Customized TabHost

Tags: android

I am not able to pass intent in customized tabHost.Please anyone help me.I try to pass intent from customtabactivity.java to  firsttab.java which contains the firsttab.xml as setcontentview.

### Main.xml

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0.5dip"
            android:background="#ff0000" />
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dip" android:layout_marginRight="0dip" />
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#696969" />
        <View android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="2dip"
            android:background="#000" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
            <include layout="@layout/firsttab"/>
            </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

### CustomTabHost.java

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.Window;
 import android.widget.TabHost;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;
 import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
 import android.content.Intent;
 public class CustomTabActivity extends Activity {

private TabHost mTabHost;

private void setupTabHost() {
    mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    mTabHost.setup();





}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // construct the tabhost
     requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);


        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawable.headphones);
    setupTabHost();
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);


    setupTab1(new TextView(this), "Showcase");
    setupTab2(new TextView(this), "Catalogue");


}

private void setupTab1(final View view, final String tag) {
    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);

    TabSpec setContent1 = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {

            return view;}
    });


    mTabHost.addTab(setContent1);

}
private void setupTab2(final View view, final String tag) {
    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);

    TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {

            return view;}
    });

    mTabHost.addTab(setContent);

}

private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;
}
```

}

### firsttab.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
>
 <LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="20dip"

 android:id="@+id/relative">
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/New_Release"
android:textSize="15dip"

android:typeface="serif" 
android:layout_weight="1"/>
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Featured_Artist"
android:textSize="15dip"
android:typeface="serif" 
android:layout_weight="1"/>
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Crew_Picks"
android:textSize="15dip"

android:typeface="serif" 
android:layout_weight="1"/> 
</LinearLayout>     
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:paddingTop="20dip"
   android:layout_below="@id/relative">

  <ImageView
   android:layout_width="55dip"
   android:layout_height="75dip"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:src="@drawable/da"
    android:padding="2dip"
   android:id="@+id/image1"/>
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="55dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image1"
android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/dd"
    android:padding="2dip"
    android:id="@+id/image2"
/>  
   <ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="148dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image2"

    android:src="@drawable/dd"
    android:padding="2dip"
    android:id="@+id/image3"/>
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="55dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    android:src="@drawable/da"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:padding="2dip"
     android:id="@+id/image4"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
     <ImageView
     android:layout_width="55dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"

android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image4" 
android:padding="2dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/dd"
   android:id="@+id/image5"
    />      
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="55dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
android:layout_below="@id/image1" 
android:padding="2dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:id="@+id/image6"
     android:src="@drawable/dd"/>
   <ImageView
     android:layout_width="55dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/image2"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image6"
android:padding="2dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:id="@+id/image7"
    android:src="@drawable/da"

     />             

   <ImageView
    android:layout_width="55dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_below="@id/image4" 
android:padding="2dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:id="@+id/image9"
     android:src="@drawable/da"

 />   
<ImageView
     android:layout_width="55dip"
    android:layout_height="75dip"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image9"
android:padding="2dip"
android:layout_below="@id/image5"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:id="@+id/image8"
    android:src="@drawable/dd"

   />          
  </RelativeLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

### firsttab.java

```
  public class firsttab extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* First Tab Content */

    setContentView(R.layout.firsttab);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Hi This will use full to create costume tabhost also if you want to switch activity in single tab you can create ActivityGroup

```
public class MyTabHost extends TabActivity 
{   
public static TabHost tabHost;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost 
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab



    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyFirst1.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("MyFirst1").setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.image1)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyFirst2.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("MyFirst2").setIndicator("",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.image2)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

}

Comment: I want to pass intent in my program.Where to call the intent.I try to call But I can't.

Comment: As I have created "spec" see that code that will pass the intent.